# Can we create an object outside of methods but inside the class? If yes then what's the purpose of creating an object outside the class?

Tags: java, class, object

```
public class C 
{
    public void p() { System.out.println(" method p"); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {System.out.println(" main method");}

    C c1 = new C(); // Why java allows this? that is, creating object outside of 
                 //the methods but inside the class? 
                 //For what purpose does Java allowed this? when is this needed?

    c1.p(); //This generates error, Why is this not allowed?
}
```

Comment: c1 is member of C. Classes should be allowed to have members right?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You question is not clear to me. "Can we create an object outside of methods but inside the class?" - Yes. You can.     "what's the purpose of creating an object outside the class?" How is it related to the code posted ? How is it related to the first part of the problem ?

Comment: I don't understand clearly what is the problem, But java allow creating objects inside a class because two things, First public objects that can be used from multiple methods and second because of aggregation and composition relationships.

Comment: You can call a static method, by the way

Comment: @cricket_007 you can't call any type of method unless it is called inside another method or in a static block, or is used to assign a variable.

Comment: **Can we create an object outside of methods but inside the class? ANS is yes** because sometime we may need the object (C1) to be declare globally to access (C1) in all the methods inside the class. **That is the purpose of creating an object outside the class**  to my knowledge.But methods call should be happen inside a method not outside the method

Comment: @Nitish - I assume you meant to say: "If yes then what's the purpose of creating an object outside the method?" and not "outside the class?" If so, please take a look at my answer.

Comment: Please understand: this site is not meant as to work as "programming school". The things you are asking for are super basic. They are covered in any good book or tutorial about Java. Don't expect us to explain things to you that have been documented a zillion times.

Answer (score 1):

`C c1 = new C();` is a field declaration.
During the field declaration, it is valid to assign to it a value.

The `c1.p();` statement is not invoked inside a method or a block (static or instance block).
It is valid to do it in a method or a block without other requirements.

But if you do it in another place, it has to be necessarily be used to assign a field you are declaring.

For example, this is legal :

```
public class C 
{
    public void p() { System.out.println(" method p"); }

    public C newC(){
       return new C();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {System.out.println(" main method");}

    C c1 = new C(); // Why java allows this? that is, creating object outside of 
                 //the methods but inside the class? 
                 //For what purpose does Java allowed this? when is this needed?

    C c2 = c1.newC(); 

   public void myMethod(){
      c1.p(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: `C c2 = c1.p();` that is not legal.

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
C c1 = new C();
```

It's an attribute to class C

```
c1.p();
```

is a call to some method, it's not allowed to call it in the scope, you could call the method in other class method or in this class but inside a method. it's just the scope

Comment: The question was why it's not allowed

Answer (score 0):

```
C c1 = new C();
```

Means you create class variable of type `C` named `c1` and initialize it. You could instead initialize it to `null`

```
C c1 = null;
```

Or not at all

```
C c1;
```

However you can't use it out of a method scope, like calling the `p()` method.

Comment: When you say "However you can't use it out of a method scope, like calling the p() method."
Why can't we call the p method? what's the reason? It is not out of scope as it is within the class.

Comment: @Nitish The class provides definitions, not functionality. Any use of the `c1` instance must be inside another method scope.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we create an object outside of methods but inside the class?

**Yes. Of Course**

> If yes then what's the purpose of creating an object outside the <strike>class</strike> method (I think you mean method)?

If you want instances of your class to maintain the state of another object, then how else would you expect to do so.

Consider the following class:

```
class C
{
    // member of C instances
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // constructor
    public C ()
    {}

    // How else would you add to the member list if 
    // it wasn't declared outside of methods?
    public void addString (String s)
    {
        list.add (s);
    }

    // return the size of the list
    public int count ()
    {
        // Should I create a new list in here... No, that wouldn't make
        // sense. I should return the size of the member list that 
        // strings may have been added to with the addString method.
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

Let's see this in action:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    // Create a new C instance
    C c = new C();

    // I sure hope C is keeping track of all these strings??
    c.addString( "1" );
    c.addString( "2" );

    // Should print 2
    System.out.println( "Number of strings: " + c.count() );
}
```